# Native code as separate process vs JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My current project involves an Android app with some existing native code. As far as I know, I can either use the code as a separate binary which will be run in a separate process or through JNI which allows simpler communication.

Is it true that JNI should usually be preferred over the over approach? The native code (which was written to be compiled into a UNIX binary) really relies on continous performance. It should not be affected by other code (e.g. Android views, activities, processes, threads...) at all, at least in theory. Practically, our goal is to keep it as performant as possible. Will JNI cause performance problems, especially in the terms of communication overhead and VM threading?

A separated binary would have the benefits
- that it is simple to maintain
- that the existing native code base does not have to be changed (except from compatibility changes, of course)
- that the process running the separated binary might be less vulnerable to performance impacts than the single-process JNI solution.

Comment: If you can tolerate the overhead of sockets or pipes to communicate with the binary, by all means keep it a separate process.

Comment: @EJP I will have to process output, primarily, and the communication itself is not performance critical, it simply must not affect the performance of the native code. Why is it generally considered "better" to use JNI?

Comment: Calling a function in the same process will generally be much faster than marshalling arguments and passing them through an IPC mechanism, and the difference gets even larger if you have to pass large amounts of data around.  Native code won't be paused by the GC unless it calls back in through JNI (in Dalvik -- not sure about ART in Lollipop).  Your code will be affected by all the other stuff going on in the system whether you're in a separate thread or a separate process.

Comment: @fadden does running Linux shell commands through JNI is has better performance than though the JavaVM?